# Python script with a loop and a conditional statemen

Tags: python

i am trying to create a script with  a loop and a conditional statement to find the value of the number of dogs in the following collection of key-value pairs but i am just not getting my head around it.

so how do i find the value of the number of dogs in the following collection of key-value pairs,

Cheers
Vlad

```
 for value in KC.values():
  if 'Dogs' in value:
       return value
```

Comment: `Dog` isn't a value, its a (capitalized version of) key, whats wrong with `KC.get('dogs')`?

Comment: did you print values? You'll get something like 7,12,21,3,3 ... no "Dogs" in it.

Comment: You do not need to loop - simply get the value:  `print( KC.get("Dogs","Not inside dictionary"))` - you also have a spelling mistake in your key, they need to match EXACTLY - with a normal `KC["Dogs"]` you get an exception, dict.get(...) is more lenient and allows to get a default value instead

Comment: @Sayse i am looking for an if  statement and a loop to  be included in this, do you have any suggestions how to write it like that?

Comment: If you want to make your serach case-insentive you could use `value.lower()` and 'Dogs.lower()` (or just type your search string in lowercase).

Comment: @PatrickArtner thanks Patric, but i am looking for it to be a Loop and an if statement for a task  in college, any suggestions?

Comment: You can also get tuples of (key, value) from your dict:  `print(KC.items())` - you could construct something loop-ish with that and use comparisons on lower-cased strings of the first item in the tuple (the key) - but then you forgoe any advantages of the dict to begin with.

Comment: Any ideas for your task? Yeah:  do it, don't ask here - you got enough pointers and methods of dicts to solve it. Also: SyntaxError - you use return but are not inside a function - so your [mre] is seriously faulty.

Comment: for loops and conditionals to make sense you would need to use some other data structure (like nested (2d) lists) not a dictionary

Comment: Possible Duplicate:  [case-insensitive-dictionary-search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296499/case-insensitive-dictionary-search)

Answer (score 1):

You have .values(), which will give you the values. E.g 7, 12, 21, 3, 3

Otherwise you can use .keys(), which will give you "Cats", "hamsters" etc.

Or you can simply check:

```
if "dogs" in KC:
    return KC["dogs"]
```

Keep in mind that coding is case sensitive. So "Dogs" and "dogs" are not the same.

Comment: the same thing can be achieved with a simple `return KC.get('dogs')` without any if statements

Comment: KC= {'Cats':7,'hamsters':12,'Birds':21,'dogs':3,'Chicken':3 }
    for value in KC.values():
       if "dogs" in KC:
          return KC["dogs"]
 would this be a correct one?

Comment: No boomking - it would needlessly iterate all values if the key is not in the dict and return on the first iteration if it is in the dict which makes no sense at all

Comment: so how do i   find the value of the number of dogs in the following collection of key-value pairs, apologies i have been at it for too long, my head is just spinning :(

Comment: @boomkings you want the number to be the key? also use `KC.get('dogs')` to get the number of dogs and don't use loops or conditionals. Unless you need case insensitivity but that would be done slightly differently anyways

Comment: and if i used a loop and an if how would i do that @Matiiss

Comment: @boomkings you can do sth like `for key, value in KC.items(): if key == 'dogs': return value` but that is completely needless if using a dictionary (unless case insensitivity matters or sth else), such a loop better fits some 2d list