# How can I make user entries case-insensitive in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, dictionary, case-insensitive

I am following [FreeCodeCamp's Python tutorial](https://youtu.be/rfscVS0vtbw?si=mupGnwKgOaiGCrJc&t=7637). I would like to know how I can make user entries case-insensitive.

Here is the example code.

```
month_conversions = {
    "Jan": "January",
    "Feb": "February",
    "Mar": "March",
    "Apr": "April",
    "May": "May",
    "Jun": "June",
    "Jul": "July",
    "Aug": "August",
    "Sep": "September",
    "Oct": "October",
    "Nov": "November",
    "Dec": "December",
}

print(month_conversions.get("Jan")
```

And it will always return "January".

Suppose I wanted the flexibility of the user entering "JAN", "jan" and "Jan" and the programme always returning "January". How would I do that?

I re-wrote the months into a list, then referred to their index which should produce the whole name of the month. Like this:

```
month_key = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]

month_conversions = {
    month_key[0]: "January",
    month_key[1]: "February",
    month_key[2]: "March",
    month_key[3]: "April",
    month_key[4]: "May",
    month_key[5]: "June",
    month_key[6]: "July",
    month_key[7]: "August",
    month_key[8]: "September",
    month_key[9]: "October",
    month_key[10]: "November",
    month_key[11]: "December",
}

print(month_conversions.get("Jan"))
```

And I was happy it gave me January! But using the `.get` command, how can I ensure that a user can type "JAN", "jan" and "Jan" and return "January"?

Comment: Convert the user's input to all lower-case via `.lower()`, and have all the keys in your dictionary be in lower case.  (All upper-case would also work, for English at least - but there are languages with characters that cannot start a word, and therefore may not have an upper-case version.  I recommend lower case to avoid problems in such situations.)

Comment: See e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3296646/3890632)

Comment: Semi-Related , You might look at `casefold()` rather than `lower()` [casefold() if for caseless string matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45745661/lower-vs-casefold-in-string-matching-and-converting-to-lowercase)

Answer (score 2):

As @Jon commented, `casefold()` is better than `lower()`

We can use `casefold()`

One way is to lowercase your dictionary key.

```
month_conversions = {
    "jan": "January",
    "feb": "February",
    "mar": "March",
    "apr": "April",
    "may": "May",
    "jun": "June",
    "jul": "July",
    "aug": "August",
    "sep": "September",
    "oct": "October",
    "nov": "November",
    "dec": "December",
}
```

then ask user

```
user = input('Enter month please : ')
l_case = user.casefold()
print(month_conversions.get(l_case))
```

#output

```
Enter month please : Jan
January

Enter month please : JAN
January

Enter month please : jan
January
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Goku's solution, you can use `string.capitalize()` in Python without changing the key of your dictionary.

```
user = input('Enter month please : ')
print(month_conversions.get(user.capitalize()))
```

The `capitalize` method will convert first character to uppercase and all other to lowercase.